# TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleDelete' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React & below code from "[React Tutorial for Beginners [React js] YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0&t=1568s)" is throwing weird error as below, please help

**Code**

```
handleDelete = () => {
console.log("Delete");
};


render() {
    console.log("this outside", this);
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map(function (cnt) {
          //console.log(cnt);
          console.log("this inside", this);
          //new properties / props are added here
          return (
            <Counter
              key={cnt.id}
              onDelete={this.handleDelete}
              value={cnt.value}
              id={cnt.id}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I think that because you used the word function - the this refers to the cnt and not the class. Try changing your map function into an arrow function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `onDelete={this.handleDelete}` is inside scope `{this.state.counters.map(function (cnt) {`.

You should use:

```
        {this.state.counters.map(cnt) => { // autobind using arrow function
          //console.log(cnt);
          console.log("this inside", this);
          //new properties / props are added here
          return (
            <Counter
              key={cnt.id}
              onDelete={this.handleDelete}
              value={cnt.value}
              id={cnt.id}
            />
          );
        })}
```

Comment: @vikramvi : Also read up on the difference between arrow functions and regular functions. You will gain knowledge of how the context `this` works.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an arrow function you can put your this inside a variable and use it from your callback like :

```
var myComponent = this;

todos = todos.map(function(item, idx) { /*...*/ onClick= 
{myComponent.handleDelete} }
```

Comment: see more here https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/arrow-function